# network_mode host (again) in docker-compose 3.8 not working (in windows)

Tags: windows, docker-compose

According to [official ocumentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode), the following should work

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
    network_mode: host
```

(tried both `host` and `"host"`)

But it complains with `network host not found`:

```
docker-compose up -d
Starting 32f22992dc86_docker_webapp_1 ... error

ERROR: for 32f22992dc86_docker_webapp_1  Cannot start service webapp: network host not found

ERROR: for webapp  Cannot start service webapp: network host not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from [somewhere else in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#prerequisites) as well: `The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server`. Same for docker-compose `network_mode`, of course.

Comment: It's such a shame. I couldn't solve for about an hour why my port wasn't being exposed to localhost. I wanted to use it for splitting services into several docker-compose files. Thanks for providing the info

Comment: What if wsl 2 is used as backend?